# Neo4J using properties on relationships for quicker lookup?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am yet trying to make use of neo4j to perform a complex query (similar to shortest path search except I have very strange conditions applied to this search like minimum path length in terms of nodes traversed count).

My dataset contains around 2.5M nodes of one single type and around 1.5 billion edges (One single type as well). Each given node has on average 1000 directional relation to a "next" node.

Yet, I have a query that allows me to retrieve this shortest path given all of my conditions but the only way I found to have decent response time (under one second) is to actually limit the number of results after each new node added to the path, filter it, order it and then pursue to the next node (This is kind of a greedy algorithm I suppose).

I'd like to limit them a lot less than I do in order to yield more path as a result, but the problem is the exponential complexity of this search that makes going from `LIMIT 40` to `LIMIT 60` usually a matter of x10 ~ x100 processing time.

This being said, I am yet evaluating several solutions to increase the speed of the request but I'm quite unsure of the result they will yield as I'm not sure about how neo4j really stores my data internally.

The solution I think about yet is to actually add a property to my relationships which would be an integer in between 1 and 15 because I usually will only query the relationships that have one or two max different values for this property. (like only relationships that have this property to 8 or 9 for example).

As I can guess yet, for each relationship, neo4j then have to gather the original node properties and use it to apply my further filters which takes a very long time when crossing 4 nodes long path with 1000 relationships each (I guess O(1000^4)). Am I right ?

With relationship properties, will it have direct access to it without further data fetching ? Is there any chance it will make my queries faster? How are neo4j edges properties stored ?

**UPDATE**

Following  @logisima 's advice I've written a procedure directly with the Java traversal API of neo4j. I then switched to the raw Java procedure API of Neo4J to leverage even more power and flexibility as my use case required it.

The results are really good : the lower bound complexity is overall a little less thant it was before but the higher bound is like ten time faster and when at least some of the nodes that will be used for the traversal are in the cache of Neo4j, the performances just becomes astonishing (depth 20 in less than a second for one of my tests when I only need depth 4 usually).

But that's not all. The procedures makes it very very easily customisable while keeping the performances at their best and optimizing every single operation at its best. The results is that I can use far more powerful filters in far less computing time and can easily update my procedure to add new features. Last but not least Procedures are very easily pluggable with spring-data for neo4j (which I use to connect neo4j to my HTTP API). Where as with cypher, I would have to auto generate the queries (as being very complex, there was like 30 java classes to do the trick properly) and I should have used jdbc for neo4j while handling a separate connection pool only for this request. Cannot recommend more to use the awesome neo4j java API.

Thanks again @logisima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to do a **custom shortespath** algo, then you should write a [cypher procedure](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/server-extending/#procedures) with the **[traversal API](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorial-traversal/)**.

The principe of Cypher is to make `pattern matching`, and you want to traverse the graph in a specific way to find your good solution.

The response time should be really faster for your use-case !

Comment: Thanks for your input! Great news then, I will try this right away, and hope I will be able to yield even better response time. I'll let you know about the results.
This being said, I'm curious about my first original question because I'd like to understand how neo4j works more precisely. Would storing the properties onto the relationships make the query faster ? slower ? same ?

Comment: The sooner you can filter, better it is ! So if by adding a prop on the edge helps you to not go to the ending node it's perfect ! Or better you can also put the property in the relationship type, so Neo4j doesn;'t have to retrive  the rel's props.

Comment: Awesome so I could even create relations like `NEXT1`, `NEXT2` ... `NEXT15` and would in most case have 7.5 times less child nodes to check each time right (I'm usually querying 2 of those relations but not much more)?  So in theory, this could divide by 7.5 my request times right? Also, I'm trying to use the java API as you mentionned but I am strugging with one thing : I'm using breadth first search and I'd like to order and limit the results after each new depth is reached but PathExpander doesn't seem to be the right place to do this and neither evaluators, any idea on how I could do this?

Comment: And I'm also wondering: does the length of the relationship name will increase the hard drive memory used? Will it also increase querying durations if longer? Or is there some internal id/index replacement of this relationships names?

Comment: everything in neo4j has an internal id

Comment: Thanks to your input, I've managed to answer all of my problems in terms of performances (check out my post edits for further details)

Comment: Good news. Have fun now !